# Yeoman Angular Node App, Compass Failed on Grunt Serve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, yeoman

Don't know why this is happening used

```
'npm install -g compass'
```

and it shows the tree confirming install. But I can't seem to check compass's version. So it may or may not be in there, it is present in the package.json file...anyway here is the code:

```
grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task
    Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh -c compass --version
    /bin/sh: compass: command not found
     Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.


    Execution Time (2015-12-04 20:10:42 UTC)
    loading tasks                  384ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 78%
    loading grunt-contrib-compass   48ms  ▇▇▇▇ 10%
    compass:server                  58ms  ▇▇▇▇ 12%
    Total 493ms Use --force to continue.

        Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-12-04 20:10:41 UTC)
loading tasks      338ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 16%
wiredep:app        320ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 15%
wiredep:test        27ms  ▇▇ 1%
wiredep:sass        50ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
concurrent:server   1.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 63%
```

Comment: As it says on [compass' page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compass), you should "Ensure compass is already installed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install compass and you'll be fine:

http://compass-style.org/install/

(the npm package is just a wrapper for actual compass)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the answer...so I have a deep misunderstanding of gems then, I thought they were dependencies for a rails app. But they are installed locally?

Comment: As npm packages can be depencies for your node.js server app, so *can* gems be depencies for your ruby app. But gems are also, as npm packages, used to do much more than just server-side apps.